# bug display of many Highcharts and Highstocks on the same page

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I don't understand why i have some problem of display at some Highstocks charts, please go to :

--> https://www.astracontrol.com/

--> "ACCES DEMO" button

--> "section de démonstration" link

--> links "Centrale 1" and/or "BOYER"

You will seeing "Performance" charts, why only zoom YTD is available?

You will seeing "Performance hebdomadaire sur le mois glissant" charts, why tooltip is reverse and working only for first and last point?

You will seeing "Relevés de production" charts, why first column is not showing correctly and not working for tooltip?

Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure but maybe you have no enough data to be shown so 1m, 3m, 6m are disabled.

Comment: Thanks, maybe for the first but concerning second and third question, have you the same problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning I advice familiar with the errors which you have in console, you need to have sorted data via x ascending. If you will fix it, you can [minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange) parameter

Answer (score 0):

I work also in the renewable energies in a large structure ... I'm developing a tool stats ( including solar) using these superb library and HighStock HighChart .. don't worry , we are not competitors .. our tools are developped for our own plants .... It is enough to do :-)

So we will help each other because it's perfectly the philosophy of renewable ... at least it's mine ;-)

Q1 : why only zoom YTD is available ?

Check out this official HighStock example and you will understand better ( playing a bit with the selected field : from RangeSelector ) ... it will also help you validate Anto' avice advice on insufficient amounts of data to display minimum a whole month  .. . put in RangeSelector buttons  the days or the hours to see ... you will know if it is this CAUSED - below .

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/

```
$ (' # container ') . Highcharts (' StockChart ', {
    chart: {
        events : {
            load : function ( ) {

                / / Set up the updating of the chart Each second
                var series = this.series [0];
                setInterval ( function () {
                    var x = ( new Date ()). getTime (), / / current time
                    y = Math.round ( Math.random () * 100);
                    series.addPoint ( [x , y] , true, true);
                } , 1000) ;
            }
        }
    }

    rangeSelector : {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1
            type: ' minute '
            text: '1 M '
        } {
            count: 5
            type: ' minute '
            text: '5 M '
        } {
            type: ' all' ,
            text: 'All'
        } ]
        inputEnabled : false,
        selected: 1
    }
```

Q2 : Will seeing " Weekly Performance on the rolling months " charts , why tooltip is reverse and working only for first and last item ?

Probably because your points are inserted with a descending chronological order and the tooltip in ascending index works (check your x datetime coordinates)  ... By this way, the console of browser (F12) reminded you this mabny many times : http://www.highcharts.com/errors/ 15 ... that's what Sebastian just say you above .

Q3 : You Will seeing " Records of production" charts , why first column is not showing Correctly and not working for tooltip ?

Same as the previous question ...

Hope it helps tou and happy to share some informations or methods ...

A +

Ecosmose .

--- French original -----
Salut Josse !

Je bosse aussi dans le renouvelable dans une grande structure... Je suis en train de développer un outil de stats (notamment solaire) à l'aide de ces superbes library HighStock et HighChart .. ne t'inquiète pas , nous ne sommes pas concurrents.. nos outils sont developpés pour nos propres centrales.... On a bien assez à faire.

Donc on va s'entraider car ç'est parfaitement la philosophie du renouvelable... du moins, c'est la mienne ;-)

why only zoom YTD is available?

Regarde cet exemple officiel de HighStock et tu comprendras mieux (joue un peu avec le champ selected: de RangeSelector)... cela te permettra aussi de valider les conseils de Anto sur la quantités insuffisantes de données pour afficher à minima un mois entier... En ajouter les jours voir les heures dans les boutons de RangeSelector , tu pourras savoir si c'est bien cette causee - ci.

--- Some Link above ..

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart : {
            events : {
                load : function() {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 1
        },
```

You will seeing "Performance hebdomadaire sur le mois glissant" charts, why tooltip is reverse and working only for first and last point?

Certainement parce que tes points sont insérer avec un ordre chronologique décroissant et que le tooltip fonctionne en index ... à ce propos , la console d'un browser te le rappele maintes fois : highcharts.com/errors/15 ... c'est ce que te rappeles Sebastien juste au -dessus.

You will seeing "Relevés de production" charts, why first column is not showing correctly and not working for tooltip?

Idem que la question précédente ...

Au plaisir de partager quelques infos ou méthodes avec toi ...

A+

Ecosmose.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use English on the main SO site, as a "lowest common denominator" for all other users. You can pass your post through Google Translate or similar. Don't worry about making it perfect; other users may edit your post to fix errors caused by translation.